# Embedded Firebird unload delay

Tags: firebird

After I close my application fbclient.dll remains in memory for about 3 seconds. So it locks the database file and prevents my application from unloading. I'm using Firebird embedded.

The problem is related to events. I signup to events using isc_que_events. If I don't signup to events dll unloads instantly.

I faced this problem in previous FB versions and now in 2.1.3 it's still the same.

The same issue is described here http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-15, but it's resolved as "Cannot Reproduce".

Is anybody facing this problem or there's something wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you submint something in Firebird Tracker ?

Comment: No< I can see this ticket http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-15 and it's closed now as "Cannot Reproduce"

Comment: Do you ubsubscribe correctly (isc_cancel_events, iirc) before trying to unload?

Comment: I have the same problem without using any events - it even happens if all I do is "connecting" to my database file and closing it again. It's very annoying, especially during development. I've already tried ClearAllPools() even though I'm disabling pooling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewritten my logic and now I don't need to subscribe to local events. So it's not a problem for me anymore. But the issue still remains.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the .NET Provider? This one keeps connections open in a pool, maybe this is the problem. Try clearing the connection pool before exiting your application:

```
FbConnection.ClearAllPools();
```

Comment: No I'm using native Firebird API

Comment: I AM using the .NET provider, and you just helped me solve the problem I've been working on all day.  I chose to just call ClearPool(connection), and it worked great.